# get value by json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I am fetching some data from database and want to show these values in a combo in javascript but combo box is not populating any value, perhaps i am doing something wrong in json or javascript, can anybody tell me where i am wrong? From db 5 values are coming in while loop

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(); 

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()){
t1=rs.getString(1);
myList.add(t1);
 jsonObj.put("name",myList.toArray());
}
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());
```

want to get above values in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#combo").change(function() {
$.getJSON('combo.jsp', {count : this.value}, function(responseData) {
$("#combo1").empty().append ("<option>please select</option>");
var json = $.parseJSON(responseData);
var myValues = json.name;
for (var idx in myValues) {
$("#combo1").append(
    $("<option></option>").html(myValues[idx]).val(myValues[idx])
);
}
});
});          
    </script>
```

Please anybody give me some idea at least, i am not able to find any solution

Comment: put some debugging statements in your code and you'll probably locate the problem. alert() in js and System.err.println() in Java.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx i am getting value in server side but i do not know whether jsonObj is keeping values correctly or not? have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248383/retrieve-more-than-one-value-by-json-array-objects

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx any solution my friend?

Comment: use firebug to see the returned json object from your ajax call. when you get that, paste into your question to clarify.

Comment: @DmitryB thanks but can you give me any idea to this question where i have elaborated : [please see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248383/retrieve-more-than-one-value-by-json-array-objects)

Comment: @DmitryB i am trying in firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There was a syntax error
2. `parseJSON` is not needed when data is retrieved using `getJSON`

Assuming the response json is of struture:
    {name={prop1:value1 , prop2: valu2, prop3:value3 ..... }}

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#combo").change(function () {
            $.getJSON('combo.jsp', {
                count: this.value
            }, function (responseData) {
                $("#combo1").empty().append("<option>please select</option>");
                var myValues = responseData.name;
                for (var idx in myValues) {
                    $("#combo1").append(
                    $("<option></option>").html(myValues[idx]).val(myValues[idx]));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Or if the structure is:
    {name=[value1 , valu2, value3, ..... ]}

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#combo").change(function () {
            $.getJSON('combo.jsp', {
                count: this.value
            }, function (responseData) {
                $("#combo1").empty().append("<option>please select</option>");
                var myValues = responseData.name;
                for (var i=0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
                    $("#combo1").append(
                    $("<option></option>").html(myValues[i]).val(myValues[i]));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot Diode, it worked like a charm. I just need one more help, that is how to send to a servlet by onchange event like i am sending it to combo.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which browser you are using. But afaik, insert html directly by using `innerHTML` is not working on some browser.
You should try this way:

```
$("#combo1")[0].options.add(new Option(label, value));
```

label indicates the string inner "option"
value indicates the attribute "value" of the "option"

In your code:

```
for (var i = 0, val; val = myValues[i]; i++)
{
    $("#combo1")[0].options.add(new Option(val, val));
}
```

Comment: thanks kelvin but where to add this code? can you please clarify little bit

Comment: $("#combo1").append(
    $("<option></option>").html(myValues[idx]).val(myValues[idx])
);

Comment: thanks kelvin for your suggestion but it is not working have you tested in my friend?

Comment: it is showing javascript error, if possible can you please edit my javascript code and add your modified code so that everybody can see it

Comment: no friend it is not populating value in combobox, i think some error is there in server side JSON

Answer (score 0):

I doubt u are getting values from your getJSON CALL .. Use Firebug to see if you are getting response for your ajax call. And use console.log(responseData); inside $.getJSON('combo.jsp', {count : this.value}, function(responseData) {

console.log(responseData);
});

Hi try this:

```
var options = '';
$.getJSON('combo.jsp', {
    count: this.value
}, function (responseData) {
    $.map(responseData, function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        //alert(item.code);
        options += '<option value="' + item.code + '">' + item.description + '</option>';
    });
}
);
$("#combo").html(options);
```

Comment: ok i am trying in firebug but if possible provide a solution to this above problem by editing my json or javascript code

Comment: var options = '';
  $.getJSON('combo.jsp', {
      count: this.value
  }, function (responseData) {
      console.log(responseData);


      $.map(responseData, function (item) {

          //alert(item.code);
          options += '<option value="' + item.code + '">' + item.description + '</option>';
      });


  }

  );
  $("#combo").html(options);

Comment: yeah thanks for your suggestion well above answer worked for me :)